# ubuntu qcow2 image for local usage

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I'm using kvm and I would like to run ubuntu server on it. My goal is to run db2 database instance for development.

Is there ready to use ubuntu qcow2 images online for such purpose?
Or should I install it from live cd?

---

I've found this instruction [UEC/Images](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_images_on_Local_Hypervisor_.28Maverick.29), but at launch I get:

```
$ kvm -fda ${floppy} -drive if=virtio,file=./disk.img -boot a
...
Nothing to boot: No such file or directory (http://ipxe.org/...)
No more network devices
No bootable device.
```

---

Solution:

I havent found pre-installed ubuntu virtual machine image online, so solution is to install it by your self.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly shouldn't install it from floppy disks. Try something like this:

```
kvm -enable-kvm \
  -drive file=./disk.img,index=0,media=disk,if=virtio \
  -drive file=./UBUNTU.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
  -boot cd ...
```

Comment: thanks already did that, I thought that these UEC images are pre-installed already.